# Does an empty value pack expansion match a type pack or optional type parameter?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, variadic-templates

I was just trying to hack up a binary literal `operator ""_b`, but got stuck trying to terminate the recursion. How to define a function which can be called using an empty explicit template parameter list, which doesn't conflict with a parameter pack overload? Then, inspiration: match the empty pack expansion to something wacky.

But GCC complains that the nonexistent types of the empty argument list don't agree with not-explicitly-required types of the parameter list. Is it supposed to work this way?

```
template< char head, char ... tail >
constexpr unsigned long long parse_binary() {
    return ( ( head - '0' ) << sizeof ... (tail) )
        + parse_binary< tail ... >(); // Error: no overload for termination.
}

template< typename = void > // I want this to match an empty pack of chars.
// template< short = 0 > // even this would do.
constexpr unsigned long long parse_binary() {
    return 0;
}

template< char ... digits >
constexpr unsigned long long operator ""_b() {
    return parse_binary< digits ... >();
}

#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::cout << 010101_b << '\n';
}
```

Note: The question isn't implementing `operator ""_b`. That problem can be solved by expanding the pack into the parameter list, and passing `std::integral_constant` types around.

Note 2: This code actually does work with a minor adjustment; see my answer below. But that doesn't directly address the question. Hmm, maybe I should have edited this instead of answering…

Comment: In general you can terminate the recursion by making the original template `template<char head, char first, char ... tail>`, and the use `template<char head, char first>` for termination - but I guess that is not what you are asking.

Comment: @BjörnPollex No, then passing two arguments would be ambiguous. Packs are allowed to be empty. A `template< char head >` and a `template< char head, char second, char ... tail >` would do the trick, but yeah, that's not the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No official word on the compliance of such tricky matching, but the given code *does* work if the two overloads are transposed.

The second, terminating overload is not visible to the first because the first resolves the name at template-definition time. Only function calls dependent on a template parameter have lookup deferred until instantiation time.

Just to be clear, **this works**:

```
template< typename = void > // Define this one first!
constexpr unsigned long long parse_binary() {
    return 0;
}

template< char head, char ... tail >
constexpr unsigned long long parse_binary() {
    return ( ( head - '0' ) << sizeof ... (tail) )
        + parse_binary< tail ... >(); // Bingo: overload found.
}
```

Comment: iirc in c++11 we have an explicit bullet that a function name is dependent if it is a template id and one of the template arguments is dependent. now in order to know that it is a template id the compiler first has to look it up to a template but that i zhink soesnt preclude a second instantiation time lookup.

Comment: yep I verified that this is a GCC bug: "parse_binary< tail ... >()" should do instantiation-dependent lookup of "parse_binary" too.

Comment: @JohannesSchaub-litb: Interesting! Did you file the bug?

Answer (score 4):

Wouldn't it be better to terminate the recursion at one character?

```
template<char Ch>
constexpr unsigned long long parse_binary(){
  return Ch - '0';
};

// second head to disambiguate
template< char head1, char head2, char ... tail >
constexpr unsigned long long parse_binary() {
    return ( ( head1 - '0' ) << sizeof ... (tail)+1 ) + parse_binary< head2, tail ... >();
}
```

In any case, the problem is that `parse_binary` for zero chars needs to be declared before the variadic version, as Clang nicely points out:

```
error: call to function 'parse_binary' that is neither visible in
      the template definition nor found by argument-dependent lookup

// call trace...

note: 'parse_binary' should be declared prior to the call site
      constexpr unsigned long long parse_binary() {
```

Comment: LOL. I just wrote my reply to Björn before scrolling down to this. As I said in the note, this is a question about parameter packs, not implementing binary literals. The elegant solution is to expand the pack in the function parameter list.

Comment: Ah, yes, you're not allowed to expand the overload candidate set unless the overloaded name is ADL dependent on a template parameter. Aha, combined with Luc's comment in chat, I think I understand now.